# cordova android install error on mac

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a phonegap app, but each time I try to add a platform I get this error:

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.mc2now.hello" at location "/Users/tony/Desktop/eclipse/eclipse"
imac-6:eclipse tony$ cd eclipse
imac-6:eclipse tony$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
    at /Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
    at _rejected (/Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /Users/tony/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

so, my question is how to add android to my path? I have tried this:

```
imac-6:eclipse tony$ export PATH=${PATH}:adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it appeared to be permission problems in the installed adt-bundle.

the following fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Development/adt-bundle
```

Comment: $ sudo chmod -R 777 /Development/adt-bundle worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your user directory `cd ~/` and edit `.bash_profile` then add `export PATH=${PATH}:adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/adt-bundle/sdk/tools` to that file.

Save, close the terminal and start it up again.

Comment: additionally, make sure your paths are correct. In your line above the platform-tools path does not have a / in front of it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my linux box.
I fixed putting android sdk "tools" subdir in my system PATH env variable.
For example:

```
export PATH="/opt/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools:$PATH"
```

You should also include "platform-tools" subdir.